# Что с описанием метки [вывод]?

Tags: обсуждение, метки

Сегодня наткнулся на метку [вывод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4) со странным описанием:

> Внешне наблюдаемые последствия вызова программы на некотором input

Что значит "*... на некотором input*"? причем здесь вообще *input*?

Comment: Сжечь этот [tag:вывод] - и с описанием метки проблем не будет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Предложил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/875709) более конкретное описание метки:

> Используйте эту метку для вопросов, которые связаны с выводом данных программой куда-либо (например, в консоль).

Новое описание писал, основываясь на использовании метки. Большинство вопросов - про вывод данных в консоль.

**Обновление**:

Новое описание утверждено.

Comment: Так-то лучше...

Answer (score 2):

Это машинный перевод с английского описания метки: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/output

Данная метка является бессмысленной, так как любая программа имеет какой-то вывод, она ничего не добавляет к классификации вопросов. В связи с этим, предпочтительно, чтобы кто-то из модераторов удалил кривое описание, не добавляя взамен другое. Мне редактор не дает заменить этот "шедевр" на пустоту, пишет, что нужно ввести минимум 20 символов.

Comment: А мне удалось. Я просто пробелы поставил, сработало: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/872172

Comment: @Зонтик Угу, я подозревал, что можно обойти с пробелами. У модераторов вроде должен быть нормальный способ сбросить описание.

Comment: *любая программа имеет какой-то вывод* Позвольте не согласиться. Вот только что запускал кнокер - он пнул девайс, обеспечив мне полчаса доступа, и завершился, а мигнувшее окно (от которого, кстати, можно и избавиться - просто лень) как-то на "вывод" совсем не тянет. Метка, тем более с учётом [censored] описания по ссылке, предполагает, что речь идёт о визуальном отображении результата работы (вывод на экран, печать и пр.). *метка является бессмысленной* И тут позвольте не согласиться - фраза "как вывести на экран" и аналогичные встречаются в вопросах не сказать чтобы редко.

Comment: @Akina она слишком обширная, понятие "вывод" объединяет слишком многое: вывод на экран, запись в файл, отправку сигнала на сетевой порт. Для вывода на экран по идее лучше использовать другие метки: [консоль] для текстового вывода, [графика] или [gui] для графического, так как они имеют более конкретное значение.

Comment: Да, смыслов, которые можно заложить - до чёртиков. Но если делать метку - то нужно остановиться на каком-то одном определённом смысле, и верстать описание под него (а потом ещё и шлёпать по рукам за неправильное применение метки). Что я, собственно, и написал в комментарии к ответу [Qwertiy](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy).

Answer (score 1):

Либо кто-то попутал input и output, либо имелось в виду, что программа должна что-то вывести на определённых входных данных.

В любом случае, мне кажется, что это описание надо переписать, а заодно добавить подробное.

Comment: Нужно, наверное, сперва определиться, что именно закладывать в эту метку. Только вывод на экран? Любой вывод, включая печать, запись в файл и пр.? Любая передача за пределы программы, включая передачу по сети, по USB и пр.?

Comment: @Akina, я думаю, stdout+stderr. И манипуляции с выводом в окно консоли. Но надо вопросы посмотреть получше.